# Problem with integrating a bootsrap template into my Angular project: When I add styling files, the app stops working

Tags: angular, bootstrap-4

I am trying to integrate a bootstrap template into my angular project which also uses bootstrap.
This is my Angular project:
[image]

And this is the "Etheral" scrolling template I am trying to integrate in first Dashboard section:
[image]

[image]

I have simply moved the Ethereal files and folders into the Dashboard component folder, and replaced the code inside the dashboard.component.html with the code inside index.html.
[image]
I am well aware that this is not the right method, but I am just trying to test whether I can integrate the Ethereal template or not.
So now, here's my dashboard.component.html file:

```
    <!--
    Ethereal by HTML5 UP
    html5up.net | @ajlkn
    Free for personal and commercial use under the CCA 3.0 license (html5up.net/license)
-->
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Ethereal by HTML5 UP</title>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, user-scalable=no" />
        <!-- <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/css/main.css" /> -->
        <!-- <noscript><link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/css/noscript.css" /></noscript> -->
      </head>
<body class="is-preload">
<!-- Page Wrapper -->
<div id="page-wrapper">

  <!-- Wrapper -->
    <div id="wrapper">
<!-- Panel (Banner) -->
<section class="panel banner right">
  <div class="content color0 span-3-75">
    <h1 class="major">Hello, my name<br />
    is Ethereal</h1>
    <p>This is <strong>Ethereal</strong>, a free site template by AJ for <a href="https://html5up.net">HTML5 UP</a>. It’s fully responsive, built on HTML5 and CSS3, and released entirely for free under the Creative Commons license. Hope you dig it :)</p>
    <ul class="actions">
      <li><a href="#first" class="button primary color1 circle icon fa-angle-right">Next</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <div class="image filtered span-1-75" data-position="25% 25%">
    <img src="images/pic01.jpg" alt="" />
  </div>
</section>

<!-- Panel (Spotlight) -->
<section class="panel spotlight medium right" id="first">
  <div class="content span-7">
    <h2 class="major">Sed etiam aenean</h2>
    <p>Mauris et ligula arcu. Proin dapibus convallis accumsan. Lorem maximus hendrerit orci, sit amet elementum massa hendrerit sed. Donec et ullamcorper ligula. Suspendisse amet potenti. Ut pretium libero eleifend euismod sed tristique. Quisque dictum magna risus, id ultricies justo sagittis vitae. Sed id odio tempor, porttitor elit amet, gravida hendrerit fringilla lorem ipsum dolor.</p>
  </div>
  <div class="image filtered tinted" data-position="top left">
    <img src="images/pic02.jpg" alt="" />
  </div>
</section>

<div class="copyright">&copy; Untitled. Design: <a href="https://html5up.net">HTML5 UP</a>.</div>

</div>

</div>

<!-- Scripts -->
<script src="assets/js/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="assets/js/browser.min.js"></script>
<script src="assets/js/breakpoints.min.js"></script>
<script src="assets/js/main.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

I have taken just first two sections of the index.html file just to test the whole thing.
However, the app wouldn't even start unless I comment out these two lines in the beginning of the html file.

```
   <!-- <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/css/main.css" /> -->
    <!-- <noscript><link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/css/noscript.css" /></noscript> -->
```

And obviously, this makes the dashboard.component.html file without any style.
If someone could explain to me:  *
1/ Why the app crashs when I add the two style lines?
2/ What's the best way to go about integrating the "Ethereal" template in my bootstrap/angular project?
3/ How I can actually fix this if it's possible?
Answering any of those questions would mean a lot to me.
Thank you!

Comment: do you see any errors on the console tab of the browser?

Answer (score 0):

put these cdn/script import code lines into index.html, also remove head section from dashboard.component.html

Comment: I did what you said, Still there is no change :/